# Cannot add component to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I read lots of same issues, but still cant fix it.
My component just dont want to add to JFrame.

```
//Game extends Canvas implements Runnable

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    for (Component c : frame.getComponents())
        System.out.println(c.getClass().getName() + ": " + c.isVisible() + " " + c.isDisplayable());
    frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    for (Component c : frame.getComponents())
        System.out.println(c.getClass().getName() + ": " + c.isVisible() + " " + c.isDisplayable());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame = frame;
    game.start();
}
```

It outputs

```
javax.swing.JRootPane: true false  
javax.swing.JRootPane: true false
```

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for faster help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is checking if the JFrame's root pane is present -- and it is. Is it displayable, prior to being rendered -- no.

- Don't use Canvas with a JFrame. Use Swing components instead.
- Understand that components are added to a JFrame's contentPane which is held by its root pane.
- Read the Swing tutorials for the details on how to code with Swing. You can find them here with the other Java tutorials [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html).

Comment: @Влад Савченко and 1. to use ComponentListener instead of whatever.isXxx, 2. to test for isDisplayable() is important after exception from RepaintManager (maybe only) 3. Container with (J)Component must be visible on the sceen, then is possible to test something, 4. AWT Component has some different rules in compare with Swing (RootPane, Canvas, Frame ....)

Comment: Actually, my problem is `Component must have a valid peer` when im trying to createBufferStrategy(2). Code above is copied from my another project and it works fine.

Comment: why is there createBufferStrategy(2), some reason to returns 10years back,

Comment: @mKorbel i dont see any other way to paint on JFrame easy. This way works in another project with same code

Comment: Also, that canvas im trying to add seems to be not displayable. `isDisplayable()` return false.

Comment: @ВладСавченко: you should read the tutorials on painting on JPanels via Swing. They will help. Never paint directly on the JFrame.